# checking for nans with intrinsics in c++

Tags: c++, floating-point, intrinsics

I'm new to using intrinsics but I wanted to write a function that takes a vector of 4 doubles computes `a > 1e-5 ? std::sqrt(a) : 0.0` my first instinct was to write this as follows

```
#include <immintrin.h>
__m256d f(__m256d a)
{
  __m256d is_valid = a > _mm256_set1_pd(1e-5);
  __m256d sqrt_val = _mm256_sqrt_pd(a);
  return is_valid * sqrt_val;
}
```

which according to gcc.godbolt.com compiles to the following

```
f(double __vector(4)):
    vsqrtpd  ymm1, ymm0
    vcmpgtpd ymm0, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
    vmulpd   ymm0, ymm1, ymm0
    ret
.LC0:
    .long   2296604913
    .long   1055193269
    .long   2296604913
    .long   1055193269
    .long   2296604913
    .long   1055193269
    .long   2296604913
    .long   1055193269
```

but i'm worried what will happen if `sqrt_val` contains a `nan`. i dont think `0.0 * nan` will work. what are the best practices to do here?

**Edit**

After reading the comment from @ChrisCooper (and @njuffa) I was linked to another stack overflow answer and so I will test for self equality and then `and` this with my result.

```
#include <immintrin.h>
__m256d f(__m256d a)
{
  __m256d is_valid = a > _mm256_set1_pd(1e-5);
  __m256d sqrt_val = _mm256_sqrt_pd(a);
  __m256d result = is_valid * sqrt_val;
  __m256d cmpeq = result == result;
  return  _mm256_and_pd(cmpeq, result);
}
```

which compiles to the following

```
f(double __vector(4)):
    vsqrtpd  ymm1, ymm0
    vcmpgtpd ymm0, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
    vmulpd   ymm0, ymm1, ymm0
    vcmpeqpd ymm1, ymm0, ymm0
    vandpd   ymm0, ymm1, ymm0
    ret
.LC0:
    .long   2296604913
    .long   1055193269
    .long   2296604913
    .long   1055193269
    .long   2296604913
    .long   1055193269
    .long   2296604913
    .long   1055193269
```

Comment: You can use [`std::isnan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan) to detect NaN values.

Comment: @JamesAdkison will that work on his intrinsic type though? I'm not so sure (and thats the whole point of the question most likely)

Comment: @Borgleader It works for C++ primitives (e.g., `double` types). "my first instinct was to write this as follows" -- I guess I just assumed the implementation was not settled and could be written in any way desired (in the event there isn't a way to do it with intrinsics).

Comment: This answer looks like it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15912796/1807078

Comment: According to documentation for `vcmpgtpd`, it returns a "quadword mask of all 1s (comparison true) or all 0s (comparison false)". So it seems to me that all you need to do is use `vandpd` to apply this mask to the result from `vsqrtpd`. If the arguments to `vsqrtpd` are NaN, the mask will be zero since the comparison returns false in that case.

Comment: @njuffa has it right. Use `_mm256_and_pd` instead of `_mm256_mul_pd`. Guaranteed correct and much faster, too.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisCooper and njuffa I've updated the question to represent your comments

Comment: You have missed the point of @njuffa's comment. You do not need any (slow) multiplications at all. Nor do you need to perform any check for NaN.

Comment: I see what you're saying and you're correct. I did miss that fact.  Thanks for clarifying Nemo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't programmed with AVX intrinsics before, so gathering information from  documentation to quickly put together the code below. It seems to work as desired for the one test case I provided.

The relevant observation is that the comparison instructions return a mask of all 1s (if result is TRUE) or all 0s (if result is FALSE). This mask can then be used to conditionally set the result of the square root to zero by ANDing the mask with the result from `vsqrtpd`. The binary representation of `0.0` in IEEE-754 double precision is all 0s.

Not having used these intrinsics before, I found the comparison predicates tricky to use. From what I understand, here we want to use the ordered comparison to get the desired behavior with respect to NaNs (that is, a comparison with a NaN should result in FALSE), so the 'O' variant. We also do not want a NaN input to trigger an exception (that is, we want the comparison to be quiet in that case), so the 'Q' variant. This means we want to use _CMP_GT_OQ.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

__m256d f (__m256d a)
{
   double em5 = 1e-5;
   __m256d v_em5 = _mm256_broadcast_sd (&em5);
   __m256d v_sqrt = _mm256_sqrt_pd (a);
   __m256d v_mask = _mm256_cmp_pd (a, v_em5, _CMP_GT_OQ);
   __m256d v_res = _mm256_and_pd (v_sqrt, v_mask);
   return v_res;
}

int main (void)
{
    __m256d arg, res;
    double args[4] = {2e-5, sqrt(-1.0), 1e-6, -1.0};
    double ress [4] = {0};

    memcpy (&arg, args, sizeof(arg));
    res = f (arg);
    memcpy (ress, &res, sizeof(res));

    printf ("args = % 23.16e  % 23.16e  % 23.16e  % 23.16e\n", 
            args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]);
    printf ("ress = % 23.16e  % 23.16e  % 23.16e  % 23.16e\n", 
            ress[0], ress[1], ress[2], ress[3]);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I compiled the above program with the Intel C compiler, the output looks like this:

```
args =  2.0000000000000002e-005  -1.#IND000000000000e+000   9.9999999999999995e-007  -1.0000000000000000e+000
ress =  4.4721359549995798e-003   0.0000000000000000e+000   0.0000000000000000e+000   0.0000000000000000e+000
```

Here, `1.#IND000000000000e+000` is a specific QNaN called INDEFINITE.

Comment: Thanks. I tested a different version (http://goo.gl/lsjzY0) using gcc 5.3.0 which supports the > operator instead of _mm256_cmp_pd and the only difference I noticed was that > operator generates the `vcmpltpd` instruction instead of the `vcmpgt_oqpd` instruction.